# Load html file into iframe in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

**Hi i am trying to load html file into iframe, but it is not working,
If i load any external url it is working**

**in Component.ts**

```
name = 'Set iframe source';
  url: string = "./add-cardIframe.component.html";
  urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

in oninit
ngOnInit() {
    this.urlSafe= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }
```

HTML File:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

getting error as Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'add-cardIframe.component.html'
any help on this issue would be great

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

TypeScript:

```
this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
      '<iframe width="100%" height="800" src="https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/"></iframe>',
    );
```

Comment: It bleeds inline styles to the whole application, they don't stay inside the iframe